# DateTime.TryParse depending of Regional settings (format), can't Parse date in format dd.M.yyyy. with . at the end of the year

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, regional-settings

Does Anyone know why It cannot be parsed. Regional settings(format) is Macedonian (North Macedonia). 
When I change Regional settings to Serbian(Latin, Serbia) it works and return d as {22.9.1972. 00:00:00}.

```
//obj.ToString() = "22.9.1972. 0:00:00" -- this is obj value and it should be parsed 

DateTime d = DateTime.MinValue;

if (DateTime.TryParse(obj.ToString(), out d))
          return d;
```

Comment: If I got the language wrong, please edit your tags to specify the correct one. It will help focus attention on your question.

Comment: To clarify, is this `mk-MK` as the culture ID?

Comment: I just tried this, and I can reproduce it - but without the "." after 1972, it's fine. Note that formatting the result in "mk-MK" produces "22.9.1972 00:00:00" for me - again, no period after 1972.

Comment: if the Regional format is ,,Macedonian (North Macedonia)" this code doesn't parse the date. With Regional format  ,,Serbia( Latin, Serbia)" it's good.